# Adapter not attached, layout skipped

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, layout, android-recyclerview

my java LogCat has this error:

`E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout.`

I tried all the solutions online but to no avail. When I click on a button in the recyclerview(list item) this Error will appear and my header do not change according to the database set. My database is working fine. can someone help me with this? I need to get this done in five days.  Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class contactsPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    AdapterUsers adapterUsers;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    List<ModelUser>userList;

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    private void checkUserStatus() {
        //get current user
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
        }
        else {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, login.class));
            finish();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts_page);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        //init user list
        userList = new ArrayList<>();

        //getall user
        getAllUsers();
    }

    private void getAllUsers () {
        //get current user
        final FirebaseUser fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        //get path of database named users
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        //get all data from path
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ModelUser modelUser = ds.getValue(ModelUser.class);

                    //get all users except currently signed in user
                    if (!modelUser.getEmail().equals(fUser.getEmail())) {
                        userList.add(modelUser);
                    }
                    //adapter
                    adapterUsers = new AdapterUsers(contactsPage.this, userList);
                    //set adapter to recycler view
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUsers);
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My adapter class are as follow:

```
package com.example.black.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.whereareu.ChatActivity;
import com.example.whereareu.R;
import com.example.whereareu.models.ModelUser;

import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder;

public class AdapterUsers extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterUsers.MyHolder>{

    Context context;
    List<ModelUser> userList;

    //constructor
    public AdapterUsers(Context context, List<ModelUser> userList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflate layout(row_users.xml)
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_users, parent, false);

        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {
        //get data
        final String hisUID = userList.get(position).getUid();
        final String userName = userList.get(position).getName();
        String userEmail = userList.get(position).getEmail();

        //set data
        holder.userName.setText(userName);
        holder.userEmail.setText(userEmail);

        //handle item click
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("hisUID", hisUID);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userList.size();
    }

    //view holder class
    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView userName, userEmail;

        public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //init views
            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            userEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userEmail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is related with your adapter class. Share your adapter class.

Comment: i shared my adapter class onto my question already :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to write adapter codes out of the for-loop.

```
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    userList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        ModelUser modelUser = ds.getValue(ModelUser.class);

                        //get all users except currently signed in user
                        if (!modelUser.getEmail().equals(fUser.getEmail())) {
                            userList.add(modelUser);
                        }
                    }
                    //adapter
                    adapterUsers = new AdapterUsers(contactsPage.this, userList);
                    //set adapter to recycler view
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUsers);

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the adapter only when the data is finished loading in the background.
You need to call `recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter)` before the layout finishes loading. I suggest you do something like:

```
public class ContactsPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...
    AdapterUsers adapterUsers = new AdapterUsers(this);
    List<ModelUser> userList = = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUsers);

        getAllUsers();
    }

    private void getAllUsers () {
        // ...
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // ...
                adapterUsers.update(userList); // You need to create this method in your adapter. Call "notifyDatasetChanged" in it.
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also it needs to be out of the loop, like @Sinan Dönmez said